# Append multiple table rows from string to existing table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My AJAX request responds with the following data in string format:

```
<tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
```

I want to append this HTML to an existing table.

```
<table id="demo">
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
</table>
```

I have already selected the table element from the DOM.

```
const table = document.getElementById('demo');
```

I would like to be able to do something like the following, but of course that is not possible using the `appendChild` method.

```
table.appendChild(xhr.responseText);
```

Is what I'm working to accomplish possible using only the DOM (without the use of libraries), and if so how can I go about using it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what [`Element#insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) was designed for. This prevents the waste that the use of `Element#innerHTML` causes when it sends all of the existing HTML through the parser again, which can be costly with large tables and in turn removes any event listeners that may be bound to the existing elements and references to the existing DOM nodes that will be destroyed.

It is generally always safer to use this method over the `Element#innerHTML`.

Here is a simple example that achieves the result you requested in your question:

```js
const rows = `
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
`;

const table = document.getElementById('demo');
table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', rows);
```

```html
<table id="demo">
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> <td>data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td colspan="3"><hr></td> </tr>
</table>
```

Here is an example that shows the behavior of each position:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('demo');

const rows = data => `
  <tr> <td>${data}</td> <td>${data}</td> <td>${data}</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>${data}</td> <td>${data}</td> <td>${data}</td> </tr>
`;
/** <= ECMAScript 2015 
 * function rows(data) { 
 *   return [ '<tr> <td>','</td> <td>','</td> <td>','</td> </tr>' +
 *            '<tr> <td>','</td> <td>','</td> <td>','</td> </tr>' ].join(data);
 * }
 **/

const insert = position => table.insertAdjacentHTML(position, rows(position));
/** <= ECMAScript 2015 
 * function insert(position) { 
 *   return table.insertAdjacentHTML(position, rows(position));
 * }
 **/

const positions = ['beforebegin', 'afterbegin', 'beforeend', 'afterend'];

positions.forEach(insert);
```

```html
<table id="demo">
  <tr> <td>existing data</td> <td>existing data</td> <td>existing data</td> </tr>
  <tr> <td>existing data</td> <td>existing data</td> <td>existing data</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add it to the end of the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```
table.innerHTML += xhr.responseText;
```

That will basically add `xhr.responseText` to the end of the HTML within the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var ajaxData = `<tr> <td>data1-1</td><td>data1-2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>data2-1</td><td>data2-2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>data3-1</td><td>data3-2</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>data4-1</td><td>data4-2</td> </tr>`;

var table = document.getElementById('thatTable');

var template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = ajaxData;
table.appendChild(template.content);
```

```css
#thatTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="thatTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Head 1</th>
    <th>Head 2</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I use a template to hold the HTML that is returned by your ajax call and then append the content of the template into your table.

I do it this way in case you already have things in the table, like in my example.